Using mockito-inline dependency instead of mockito
I have to mock static classes as well so I have used mockito-inline dependency. I am using junit 5 and mockito version is 3.x. The current dependency contains
Junit5
EasyMock 3.x
Mockito 3.x
Mockito-inline 3.x
Mockito-junit-jupiter 3.x

I tried to comment the mockito dependency and it worked, I want to understand how it worked.
